# c# Gui Update from Realtime-System nice Solution ? What Pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, user-interface, real-time

i'm looking for a nice solution on my Application. For Backgroundinformations:
i've got a real-time System in c++ on Linux. And i've a Winforms Application (soon WPF) on a Windows XP (soon Windows 7). The Communication is an TCP-IP Stream.
My Solution now is a Gui-Timer that updates the Gui with the Data from the ReaTime-System every Tick.
I think thats not a clean Solution. I want to make it better. But i dont know how.
Can you help me or can you give me a keyword that a can search it by myselfe ?
The Gui dont need to me real-time. 
Thanks in advance.
Nice Wishes
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

Only for WPF: The binding system of WPF is perfect in your case. All you have to do is to bind your code or data to controls and WPF updates if the bound data is updated.

See http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html for more information.

Comment: Hello, i know how wpf works. But hat wasnt my question. I want Tod know whats the best  way To geht he data from the realtimesystem ? I've heard about the observer pattern, will this be the Wright way ?